# Python AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'insertImage'

Tags: python, pdf, compiler-errors, pymupdf

I'am trying to add a png sign to the PDF by using a python code and the code that i am running is I am using PyMuPDF and have used fitz library.

```
import fitz

input_file = "example.pdf"
output_file = "example-with-sign.pdf"
barcode_file = "sign.png"

# define the position (upper-right corner)
image_rectangle = fitz.Rect(450,20,550,120)

# retrieve the first page of the PDF
file_handle = fitz.open(input_file)
first_page = file_handle[0]

# add the image
first_page.insertImage(image_rectangle, fileName=barcode_file)

file_handle.save(output_file)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `insert_image` (with underline): https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.insert_image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't think this really matters for this question anymore, because the comment from @Sajad probably answered it (did it?). But for next time, keep the error message just copy it into a code block in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for 'insert_image' correction. It currently works as follows:

```
import fitz

input_file = "example.pdf"
output_file = "example-with-sign.pdf"


# define the position (upper-right corner)
image_rectangle = fitz.Rect(450,20,550,120)

# retrieve the first page of the PDF
file_handle = fitz.open(input_file)
first_page = file_handle[0]

img = open("sign.png", "rb").read()  # an image file
img_xref = 0

first_page.insert_image(image_rectangle,stream=img,xref=img_xref)

file_handle.save(output_file)
```

Comment: You should be able to accept you own questions in ~48 hours or so.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with a very similar error to your question.  The `insert_image`  solution you posted is correct, but I think the reason is that from a **certain version of PyMuPDF**, **camelCase** (*which was good to use before*) was totally **deprecated**, and was replaced by **under_score_case**.  I think it's necessary to mark the **PyMuPDF version** here, just in case somebody was confused by these two coding styles when they met similar errors in the future.

Currently, I'm under `PyMuPDF==1.21.0`, in which I'm pretty sure **camelCase** was totally deprecated.  So if you met a similar error, just try to convert your method `someMethod()` into `some_method()`.

See: [doc is here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.insert_image)